# How to store and receive a byte array in hidden field?

Tags: c#

I have a byte array. I need to assign it to a hidden filed  and retrieve the result.How to achieve this?

I tried

```
var data =(byte[])hiddenField.value ;
```

but its giving a error

> *cannot convert string to bytearray.*

Comment: Why are you trying to store this in a hidden field? Also, is this asp.net, or winforms? asp.net you could use the session to store it in.

Comment: Why do you want to convert string to byte array on this situation?

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to store it in the hidden field as a string, so you could do:

```
hiddenField.Value = Convert.ToBase64String(data);
```

And then convert it back later:

```
byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(hiddenField.Value);
```

It would be a bit more thorough if you could provide an example of the data, too.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

To get this bytes:

```
byte[] bytes = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(hiddenField.Value);
```

To get string again:

```
string s = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the byte array into string and then store it inside the hidden field. However, please don't use the encoding method, **Encoding.ASCII.GetString** method to convert the byte array into string. Instead, you can use the following method to convert the byte array into string:

**Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray)**

Further, you can extract the string value from the hidden field, and again convert it back into byte array by using the following method.

**Convert.FromBase64String(string)**

And by this way you will be able to store and retrieve byte array values in a hidden field.
I have done this for storing string values in **Cookie**. Hopefully, this should also work for HiddenFields.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this method:

**1. In JavaScript**

Add a javascript function to convert array of bytes (0..127) to string:

```
function byteArrayToString(byteArray) {
    var str = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++) {
        str += byteArray[i] + ',';
    }
    str = str.slice(0, -1);
    return str;
}
function getDataFromJavascript()
{
  var somebinarydata = [18,122,96];
  return byteArrayToString(somebinarydata);
}
```

Set the hidden field value by calling a javascript function:

```
$('#<%= HiddenField1.ClientID %>').val(getDataFromJavascript());
```

**2. In C#**

Get hidden field value which is string, make an array of string of it and convert it to byte array:

```
byte[] byteArray = HiddenField1.Value.Split(',').Select(byte.Parse).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually store it as-is, but you can't store it in one field.  You must do a loop like this:

```
 if (Model.YourByteArray != null)
 {
    foreach (var item in Model.YourByteArray)
    {
       <input type="hidden" name="YourByteArray" value="@item">
    }
 }
```

A form will post this into a byte array parameter.